# How to create dynamic pages without form_for helper in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model, crud, form-for

Lets say I have a blog and inside of that blog I have blog posts(ie. all belong to "resources :posts"). The only difference that those blog posts are not going to be generated by users with the use of form_for helper but automatically by rails.

I'll try to make a simple example to make it clear...

Lets say My blog app is able to scrape YouTube and everyday it scrapes it to check what is the most viral video of the day. Then it would go and create a blog post automatically without me or other users actually typing in anything inside of the forms to create a post with that video inside it.

Lets say on the first day my blog app scrapes YouTube and retrieves: 1)url of the video to embed on the page 2)title, for the first ever post. My question is how would I pass this information to posts_controller.rb to create a new post, so that if say I go to myblogapp.com/posts/1 it would show me the first post.

Comment: `form_for` is designed to take input from users; think of a web form like this comments box, or the answer box below.  If you're explicitly *not* taking input from users, you don't want to use `form_for`, but another form of getting your data into your site.

Comment: @Makoto Thanks for your input! I understand what form_for is for and that I definitely do not need it in my case. Basically what I am trying to understand is how to create blog posts without any human interaction?

Comment: Well, that's a fair bit broader than what we can discuss, but first, you should divorce the notion of creating content from displaying content.  So long as you have a way to display a certain kind of content (i.e. you have a view for those posts), then *how* it's done is left up to you.

Comment: I think my problem is even more fundamental than creation and display of content. You see in "normal" blogs when a form is submitted, the fields of the form are sent to Rails as parameters. These parameters can then be referenced inside the controller actions, typically to perform a particular task. For example, create action `def create
  render plain: params[:article].inspect
end`.  The render method here is taking a very simple hash with a key of plain and value of params[:article].inspect. The params method is the object which represents the parameters (or fields) coming in from the form.

Comment: So at the moment I am trying to understand is how to pass those parameters directly from another class if that makes sense?

Comment: I actually do understand what you're saying here, but it's too broad.  You're effectively asking how we'd go about pulling content from online and displaying it using Rails.  That's something that is entirely too broad to discuss here.  If you had a more pointed question (i.e. you were in the process of pulling the data back, or you were having a specific problem in the view), we could help; right now, it's just too broad.

Answer (score 2):

Learn how to write a `rake` task and how to schedule that task to run periodically (daily?) with cron or some other scheduler. No need to build a form.

Comment: Why do you think that this should be a Rake task?

Comment: Thanks Chris, however I am quite confused as well

Comment: You dont need rake. Forget about form_for and controller. Try this way: make a class and scrape what you want, create another class that sort and do some verifications and then maybe save the data. now job is done. Now when you want to list it you simply list however you currently list. This is what I do in day to day base. Have a ready on Factory Design Pattern, it will help you in organising your code

Comment: Oh you are completely right! I was looking in a completely wrong direction I think. I apologize for the stupid question :) I am afraid my rep is too low to upvote your comment. But if i could i would

Comment: @MrH Your comment seems like it should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Makoto If I need to schedule a daily task via cron, I usually create a rake task and then have cron run that. How would you do it?